# Collapse d3js tree to a specified depth

Tags: d3.js, tree, depth

I'm new to d3js and javascript in general. I am trying to create a tree of more than 8000 nodes, and used the basic tree examples available and modified to display vertically.

Example data is hard coded, however, on my local server, I read the data from an external JSON file.

I would like to be able to specify the depth level to start with (collapse all node deeper than 2) and allow the user to further expand or collapse nodes.

I tried modifying the "collapse" function to check for the depth level, however, the logic is not correct.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

```js
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    
<script>

//------------------
var data =[{"sid":"1","parent":"null","name_ar":"Hashim"},{"sid":"2","parent":"1","name_ar":"wahb"},{"sid":"3","parent":"1","name_ar":"Abdulmuttaleb"},{"sid":"4","parent":"2","name_ar":"Amina"},{"sid":"5","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abutaleb"},{"sid":"6","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"7","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abbas"},{"sid":"8","parent":"3","name_ar":"Hamza"},{"sid":"9","parent":"6","name_ar":"Mohammed (Prophet)"},{"sid":"10","parent":"9","name_ar":"Alqassim"},{"sid":"11","parent":"9","name_ar":"Um Kalthoum"},{"sid":"12","parent":"9","name_ar":"Zainab"},{"sid":"13","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ruqaya"},{"sid":"14","parent":"9","name_ar":"Fatima"},{"sid":"15","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ibrahim"},{"sid":"16","parent":"9","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"17","parent":"9","name_ar":"Muhsen"},{"sid":"18","parent":"5","name_ar":"Ali"},{"sid":"19","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hassan"},{"sid":"20","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"21","parent":"20","name_ar":"Ali Zain Alabbideen"},{"sid":"22","parent":"21","name_ar":"Mohammed Baqer"},{"sid":"23","parent":"22","name_ar":"Jafar Sadeq"},{"sid":"24","parent":"23","name_ar":"Mousa Kadim"},{"sid":"25","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ali AlAreed"},{"sid":"26","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ibrahim Murtada"},{"sid":"27","parent":"26","name_ar":"Mousa (the second)"},{"sid":"28","parent":"27","name_ar":"Ahmed"},{"sid":"29","parent":"28","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"30","parent":"29","name_ar":"Abu Alqassim Mohammed"},{"sid":"31","parent":"30","name_ar":"Najm Aldeen Mahdi"}];

//need to find a way to dynamically set the "Width" as the tree is very deep
var margin = {top: 25, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 10000 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 5000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    rectW = 100,
    rectH = 30,
    root;

// zoom functionality   
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .nodeSize([110, 50]); // increased to 110 to avoid node overlap
    
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2]; });   

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(zoom) // added to call to zoom to enable zooming; it works :}
    .on("wheel.zoom", null) // disable zooming on mouse wheel scroll
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //create a name-based map for the nodes
    //which starts with an empty object and iterates over the data array, adding an entry for each node
    //for the flat array
    var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.sid] = node;
    return map;
    }, {});

    //iteratively add each child to its parents, or to the root array if no parent is found
    //for the flat array
    var treeData = [];
    data.forEach(function(node) {
        // add to parent
        var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
        if (parent) {
            // create child array if it doesn't exist
            (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
                // add node to child array
                .push(node);
        } else {
            // parent is null or missing
            treeData.push(node);
        }
    });
    root = treeData[0];
    root.x0 = height / 2;  // should this be width/2 for the vertical?
    root.y0 = 0;

    //testing using depth to open at a specified level
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
    function collapseLevel(d) {
        console.log("sid "+d.sid+" depth "+d.depth);
        if (d.children && d.depth > 2) { // doesn't work as it exits at parent depth
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapseLevel);
            d.children = null;
        }
    }
    root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);//iterate each node and collapse excluding node zero
    update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

//zoom (drag the tree around !) 
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
   nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //vertical tree by swaping y0 and x0
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          var g = d3.select(this); // The node
          
          var info = g.append('text')
             .classed('info', true)
             .attr('x', 20)
             .attr('y', 10)
             .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar + " " + d.sid });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
          // Remove the info text on mouse out.
          d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove()
    });
  ;

//rectagular nodes
nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

 nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition nodes to their new position.
//vertical
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
//vertical 
var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

```css
    <style>
    
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 18px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>

   </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide an `else if` condition, in case the `if` condition is *falsy*:

```
function collapseLevel(d) {
    if (d.children && d.depth > 1) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapseLevel);
        d.children = null;
    } else if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
    }
}
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var data =[{"sid":"1","parent":"null","name_ar":"Hashim"},{"sid":"2","parent":"1","name_ar":"wahb"},{"sid":"3","parent":"1","name_ar":"Abdulmuttaleb"},{"sid":"4","parent":"2","name_ar":"Amina"},{"sid":"5","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abutaleb"},{"sid":"6","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"7","parent":"3","name_ar":"Abbas"},{"sid":"8","parent":"3","name_ar":"Hamza"},{"sid":"9","parent":"6","name_ar":"Mohammed (Prophet)"},{"sid":"10","parent":"9","name_ar":"Alqassim"},{"sid":"11","parent":"9","name_ar":"Um Kalthoum"},{"sid":"12","parent":"9","name_ar":"Zainab"},{"sid":"13","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ruqaya"},{"sid":"14","parent":"9","name_ar":"Fatima"},{"sid":"15","parent":"9","name_ar":"Ibrahim"},{"sid":"16","parent":"9","name_ar":"Abdulla"},{"sid":"17","parent":"9","name_ar":"Muhsen"},{"sid":"18","parent":"5","name_ar":"Ali"},{"sid":"19","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hassan"},{"sid":"20","parent":"18","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"21","parent":"20","name_ar":"Ali Zain Alabbideen"},{"sid":"22","parent":"21","name_ar":"Mohammed Baqer"},{"sid":"23","parent":"22","name_ar":"Jafar Sadeq"},{"sid":"24","parent":"23","name_ar":"Mousa Kadim"},{"sid":"25","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ali AlAreed"},{"sid":"26","parent":"24","name_ar":"Ibrahim Murtada"},{"sid":"27","parent":"26","name_ar":"Mousa (the second)"},{"sid":"28","parent":"27","name_ar":"Ahmed"},{"sid":"29","parent":"28","name_ar":"Hussain"},{"sid":"30","parent":"29","name_ar":"Abu Alqassim Mohammed"},{"sid":"31","parent":"30","name_ar":"Najm Aldeen Mahdi"}];

//need to find a way to dynamically set the "Width" as the tree is very deep
var margin = {top: 25, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 10000 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 5000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 rectW = 100,
    rectH = 30,
 root;

// zoom functionality 
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .nodeSize([110, 50]); // increased to 110 to avoid node overlap
 
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2]; }); 

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .call(zoom) // added to call to zoom to enable zooming; it works :}
 .on("wheel.zoom", null) // disable zooming on mouse wheel scroll
   .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 //create a name-based map for the nodes
 //which starts with an empty object and iterates over the data array, adding an entry for each node
 //for the flat array
 var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
 map[node.sid] = node;
 return map;
 }, {});

 //iteratively add each child to its parents, or to the root array if no parent is found
 //for the flat array
 var treeData = [];
 data.forEach(function(node) {
  // add to parent
  var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
  if (parent) {
   // create child array if it doesn't exist
   (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
    // add node to child array
    .push(node);
  } else {
   // parent is null or missing
   treeData.push(node);
  }
 });
 root = treeData[0];
 root.x0 = height / 2;  // should this be width/2 for the vertical?
 root.y0 = 0;

 //testing using depth to open at a specified level
 var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
 function collapseLevel(d) {
  if (d.children && d.depth > 1) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d._children.forEach(collapseLevel);
   d.children = null;
  } else if (d.children){
      d.children.forEach(collapseLevel);
    }
 }
    root.children.forEach(collapseLevel);//iterate each node and collapse excluding node zero
 update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

//zoom (drag the tree around !) 
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
   nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //vertical tree by swaping y0 and x0
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click)
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          var g = d3.select(this); // The node
          
          var info = g.append('text')
             .classed('info', true)
             .attr('x', 20)
             .attr('y', 10)
             .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar + " " + d.sid });
 })
 .on("mouseout", function() {
          // Remove the info text on mouse out.
          d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove()
 });
  ;

//rectagular nodes
nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

 nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name_ar; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition nodes to their new position.
//vertical
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
//vertical 
var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
   .remove();

    nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

```css
<style>
 
 .node {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 18px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I changed to `d.depth > 1` because it seems to me that you want to show 2 depths by default, not 3. If I'm wrong, just change that number accordingly.